# prepare command and use startswith option with string

Tags: python-3.x

I am receiving some rule from file and would like to prepare query at run time but getting following error. any input.

```
a = "AC"
cond = "startswith"
rule = "AC"
eval("%s.%s(%s)" %(a, cond, rule))
```

[image]

Comment: Please show code as text, not as a picture.

Comment: this is sample code and try to minimal produce error. I would like to run this code.

Comment: What's unclear to you about the error message? Why did you try to use a variable called `AC` if it is not defined? Why did you not define it?

Comment: it is string, did not get u

Comment: I also did not get u, sorry.

Comment: I would like to run string command startswith using eval. can we do it, if possible

Comment: I think you mean `rule='"AC"'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you must use `eval`, use `%r` in your format string when you want to substitute in strings, to get the `repr` of the `str` (including quotes) so they remain valid string literals, not raw names; as written, you're trying to run the code `AC.startswith(AC)`, with `%r` for first and third placeholder (`eval("%r.%s(%r)" %(a, cond, rule))`) you'd be running `"AC".startswith("AC")`.

Comment: thx got it. it is new thing for me...

Answer (score 2):

Try in this way:

```
eval(("'%s'.%s('%s')" %(a, cond, rule)))
```

You forgot single quotes to define strings in function evaluation

Comment: This only works if the strings in question don't have internal single-quotes. Using `%r` is safer; it will use appropriate quotes and escaping for handling any string.